# objective c float values

Tags: objective-c, c

Why we can not store the division result of two integers into the float variable ?

```
int a = 100;
int b =50;
float temp = b/a;
```

it gives t= 0 !

also i did

```
int temp = b/a;
```

it gives t= 0 !

but when I did

```
float temp = (float)b / (float)a;
```

it gives proper result. Why so ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason why `float temp = b/a;` gives 0 while `float temp = (float)b/a;` gives 0.5 is that the compiler determines the output type of the division operation based upon the types of the operands, not the destination storage type.  Put simply:

```
int   /   int = int
float /   int = float
int   / float = float
float / float = float
```

So when you do `float temp = b/a;` you're doing in integer divide of `b` and `a`, and then storing the resulting integer (0 in your example) into a variable of type `float`.  In essence, by the time the value is converted to floating-point you have already lost the information you are looking for (assuming you wanted to do a floating-point divide), and the conversion is not going to bring it back.

In order to get the result you want (again, assuming that you want to do a floating-point divide), you need to cast at least one of the operands to `float` *before* you divide.

Comment: Anyone know the reasoning behind this compiler behavior?  Obviously, tons of combinations of integer divisions are going to result in a non-integer value, so it seems odd the compiler would just assume you want an integer back in every case.

Answer (score 3):

```
int a = 100;
int b =50;
float temp = (float)b/a;
```

Answer (score 3):

Its integer division - 50/100 is 0, the remainder (can use modulus) is 50.

You will need to use floats, whether you cast from int or start with them is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

The below statement means, you are casting your integer values into float before staring the operation

```
float temp = (float)b / (float)a;
```

So could be seen as below

```
float temp = (float)50 / (float)100;
```

then

```
float temp = 50.0 / 100.0 ;
```

And result

```
temp = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case 50/100 is 0.2. By obtaining the result for two integer numbers the result will also be in integer form so it truncates the decimal part giving you 0 alone. But in case of float it is considered as a floating division so you will get 0.2

Comment: ya but temp variable is float so why result is truncated while temp is capable to store float values ?

Comment: Because In Objective-C '/' performs integer division on integer arguments, so 4/5 is rounded to 0, 3/2 is rounded to 1, and so on. You probably want to cast some of your numbers to floating-point forms before performing division.